# Add comma separator to a numbers with 2 decimal points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I've managed to make the user input to 2 decimal points:
[image]
Below is my code for two input fields:

```
$('.ave-daily-accbalance').blur(function(){
    var num = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    var cleanNum = num.toFixed(2);
    $(this).val(cleanNum);

    });

    $('.facilitylimit').blur(function(){
    var num = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    var cleanNum = num.toFixed(2);
    $(this).val(cleanNum);

    });
```

But now I want to seperate the input with comma. So if the user inputs in 500000 - it automatically converts to 500,000.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString))
In your case you want to use the second options parameter to specify the number of decimal points you want:

```js
var num = 200000.001231;
var cleanNum = num.toLocaleString('en', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
console.log(cleanNum);
```

Note that the options argument does not work on all browser and versions. If compatibility is key, use `num.toLocaleString()` with no arguments, and trim/append decimals as needed:

```js
var num = 20000.001231;
var cleanNum = num.toLocaleString('en');
var splitNum = cleanNum.split('.');
if (splitNum.length < 2) {
  // Need to append .00 if num was an integer
  cleanNum = cleanNum + '.00';
} else {
  // Append 0 if there was only 1 decimal, otherwise trim
  // to 2 decimals
  var decimals = splitNum[1];
  decimals = decimals.length < 2 ? decimals + '0' : decimals.slice(0, 2);
  cleanNum = splitNum[0] + '.' + decimals;
}
console.log(cleanNum);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var x = 500000;
function formatNumber(num) {
    var arr = num.toFixed(2).split(".");
    return arr[0].split("").reduceRight(function(acc, num, i, orig) {
        if ("-" === num && 0 === i) {
            return num + acc;
        }
        var pos = orig.length - i - 1
        return  num + (pos && !(pos % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
    }, "") + (arr[1] ? "." + arr[1] : "");
}
console.log(formatNumber(x));
```

Comment: I tried to apply your code but I keep getting error saying num.toFixed is not a function: https://jsfiddle.net/L3s2pp7j/

Comment: @rory-h Can you please add the HTML code to your jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: @rory-h I'm pretty sure how to fix it for you, but please add your HTML code to your jsfiddle so I can see it?

Comment: @rory-h so you have 2 input fields and let's say user types a number in the first field (Example: 500000), then on the second input field we should see the number like this: 500,000.00 ?? is that what you want?

Comment: No, for both fields - when user inputs in let's say 500000 in first field , 800000 in second field, those two fields should convert their inputs to two decimal points with a comma separator. So first field will have 500,000.00 and second field would have 800,000.00

Comment: My aim of this question was to have both input fields to automatically convert user inputs to two decimal points with a comma separator.

Comment: @rory-h How are they supposed to convert their values to two decimal points with a comma separator? is there a button that user needs to click for conversion?? or those values (5000000 , 8000000) should change after user stops focusing on each element (input)??

Comment: What? I don't understand what you going on about. I'm just asking the how to automatically convert whatever user inputed in both fields into two decimal points and a comma separator.

Comment: @rory-h I think I got your question. The input fields should change while users types the number correct??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128413/discussion-between-rory-h-and-henrydev).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var n = "76432949.13354";
var nf = Number(parseFloat(n).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en');
document.write (nf);
```